How to force shiny apps to take up the whole length on mobile devices?
I created a website with several pages using R markdown.The first page just contains introductory text. The second page consists of four tabs, each for a shiny app (map or table).
It all works well on desktop. On mobile devices, the first page of text takes up the entire length of the phone - great. But the tabs with apps on them only take up a portion of the screen, within which you need to scroll, and I can't figure out why.
Min reproducible code:
---
title: "Climate Vulnerability and Readiness"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---

<style>
.justified-text {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 6em;
  margin-right: 6em;
}

/* Media query for mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .justified-text {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-top: 4em; 
  }
  .sidebar-panel, .main-panel {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .tabset-panel {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .sidebar-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .shiny-output-error {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-panel, .content {
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .titlePanel {
    padding-top: 4em; 
  }
  .shiny-bound-output {
    height: 100%;
  }
  }

/* Media query for desktop devices */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .main-panel {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
</style>

# Introduction {.tabset}
<div class="justified-text">

[Introductory text]

</div>

# Analysis {.tabset}

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Load your data
combined_vul_data <- 
 structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
"AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
"BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
), vul_capacity_Rank_2021 = c(0.709035449, 0.511126182, 0.523332101, 
NA, 0.740026186, 0.621133795, 0.446088596, 0.462491218, 0.296565054, 
0.26689445, 0.47917568, NA, 0.453936004, 0.649876424, 0.398904506, 
0.386808093, 0.27763708, 0.547525366, 0.763503499, 0.635633065
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

combined_readi_data <- structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
"AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
"BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
), readi_readiness = c(0.246442145333371, 0.410559121234659, 
0.33334509314068, 0.478714965470705, 0.268117798333208, 0.449260130429268, 
0.376037316185072, 0.50573276439272, 0.690552124980166, 0.68230738466746, 
0.447625682772037, 0.427831425066084, 0.519334145918882, 0.281041117917878, 
0.53612684461446, 0.490112049917615, 0.600207432355383, 0.333388191619152, 
0.337878182675485, 0.483057133272884)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))


# Define UI for the map and table
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
        float: left !important;
        text-align: left !important;
      }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        width: 200px;
      }
      .table-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .table-container .table-controls {
        margin-right: 2em;
      }
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .table-container {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .table-container .table-controls {
          margin-right: 0;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
        }
        .shiny-input-container {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .main-panel, .content {
          height: calc(100vh - 56px) !important;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        .main-panel {
          height: 100vh;
        }
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel(div(span("Country Rankings"), style={'padding-top: 15px'})),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Map",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_vulnerability"),
          textOutput("category_context")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          htmlOutput("map")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Table",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("table_year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("table_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_capacity")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput("vulnerability_table")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Readiness Map",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("readiness_year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("readiness_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Overall Readiness" = "readi_readiness"), selected = "readi_readiness"),
          textOutput("readiness_category_context")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          htmlOutput("readiness_map")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Readiness Table",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("readiness_table_year", "Select Year", choices = 1995:2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("readiness_table_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Economic" = "readi_economic", 
                                     "Governance" = "readi_governance", "Overall Readiness" = "readi_readiness",
                                     "Social" = "readi_social"), selected = "readi_readiness")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput("readiness_table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for the map and table
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$category_context <- renderText({
    context <- switch(input$category,
                      "vul_capacity" = "The availability of social resources for sector-specific adaptation. In some cases, these capacities reflect sustainable adaptation solutions. In other cases, they reflect capacities to put newer, more sustainable adaptations into place.", "")
    context
  })
  
  output$map <- renderGvis({
    year <- input$year
    category <- input$category
    
    # Create the column name for the selected year and category
    rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
    
    # Filter and prepare the data
    map_data <- combined_vul_data %>%
      select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
      mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
    
    
    # Update locationvar column
    map_data <- map_data %>%
      mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name))
    
    # Determine the range of the Rank values
    min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Create the map
    gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                 hovervar = "Tooltip",  
                 options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                width = "100%",
                                height = "500px"))  
  })

  output$vulnerability_table <- renderDT({
    year <- input$table_year
    category <- input$table_category

    # Prepare data for the table
    table_data <- prepare_table_data(combined_vul_data, year, category)

    # Calculate min and max rank
    min_rank <- min(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)

    # Generate a color scale
    color_scale <- colorRampPalette(c('#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000'))(max_rank - min_rank + 1)

    # Render the interactive table
    datatable(table_data, options = list(
      dom = 'Bt',
      pageLength = -1, 
      autoWidth = TRUE, 
      scrollY = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 0, className = 'dt-right')
      )
    ), 
    rownames = FALSE, 
    filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plainText = TRUE), 
    escape = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle('Rank', 
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(seq(min_rank, max_rank), color_scale),
                  color = 'black')
  })

  output$readiness_category_context <- renderText({
    context <- switch(input$readiness_category,
                      "readi_readiness" = "Overall readiness measures a country's ability to leverage investments and convert them to adaptation actions. It combines economic, governance, and social readiness scores to provide a comprehensive measure.",
                      "")
    context
  })
  
  output$readiness_map <- renderGvis({
    year <- input$readiness_year
    category <- input$readiness_category
    
    # Create the column name for the selected year and category
    rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
    
    # Filter and prepare the data
    map_data <- combined_readi_data %>%
      select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
      mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name)) %>%
      mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
    
    # Determine the range of the Rank values
    min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Create the map
    gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                 hovervar = "Tooltip",  # Use the Tooltip column
                 options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                width = "100%",
                                height = "500px"))  
  })

  output$readiness_table <- renderDT({
    year <- input$readiness_table_year
    category <- input$readiness_table_category

    # Prepare data for the table
    table_data <- prepare_table_data_readiness(combined_readi_data, year, category)

    # Calculate min and max rank
    min_rank <- min(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)

    # Generate a color scale
    color_scale <- colorRampPalette(c('#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000'))(max_rank - min_rank + 1)

    # Render the interactive table
    datatable(table_data, options = list(
      dom = 'Bt', 
      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      pageLength = -1, 
      autoWidth = TRUE, 
      scrollY = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 0, className = 'dt-right')
      )
    ), 
    rownames = FALSE, 
    filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plainText = TRUE), 
    escape = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle('Rank', 
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(seq(min_rank, max_rank), color_scale),
                  color = 'black')
  })
}

# Prepare data for the table
prepare_table_data <- function(data, year, category) {
  rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
  
  data <- data %>%
    select(ISO3, Name, !!rank_column) %>%
    rename(Rank = !!rank_column) %>%
    mutate(Rank = ifelse(is.na(Rank), "Insufficient data", Rank)) %>%
    select(Rank, Country = Name) %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(Rank))
  
  return(data)
}

# Prepare data for the readiness table
prepare_table_data_readiness <- function(data, year, category) {
  rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
  
  data <- data %>%
    select(ISO3, Name, !!rank_column) %>%
    rename(Rank = !!rank_column) %>%
    mutate(Rank = ifelse(is.na(Rank), "Insufficient data", Rank)) %>%
    select(Rank, Country = Name) %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(Rank))
  
  return(data)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```


Provide a minimal, reproducible example of the app.

@Jan, thanks for looking into this. I was hoping it was just a simple tweak to the code I'd pasted that would fix it. I've added the code and data now in as a reduced format as I could manage. It needs to be published though to see the issue on mobile devices. It's here for now: https://accessibleresearch.shinyapps.io/Climate_Vulnerability_vs_Readiness/

What do you think about the result if you add .shiny-frame { height: 100vh; } to your media query for mobile devices?

I think it's exactly what I wanted - thanks Jan!!! I noticed something strange on my phone though and wondering if it happens for you too. When I first open https://accessibleresearch.shinyapps.io/backup, the map is really wide and i have to scroll to the right to view it. However, after I reload it once or twice, it shows correctly (entire map fits inside the screen). Any idea why this happens and/or how to resolve it?

Yes, I can confirm this behavior, I have to investigate what is the reason for this. How do you would like to proceed here? Shall I write a short answer for the initial question with the solution above or do you would like to have the follow-up-answer also included?

If you can include the follow-up answer as well, that would be great. I think it can all be included since it falls under the umbrella of having the display appear on phones as it does on the desktop. But definitely at least the solution you provided as an answer because I searched for some time and could not find a solution. I imagine this will a huge help to others.

The reason why the whole length is not taken into account is that the whole content on the second tab is rendered into an iframe and this frame has a fixed height by default. In order to use the full view height you can add this CSS:
.shiny-frame { 
  height: 100vh; 
}

Concerning the other point why the map is initially not fitting into the screen size it seems to be like this: You currently assign width = "100%" inside gvisGeoChart(). This 100% relate to an initial rendering inside a full screen mode. A possibility is of course to set fixed width here, however, this is maybe not a convenient solution.
What generally would be the optimal solution is to trigger a re-rendering of the image, e.g. if you visit its tab. However, due to several Javascript topics I could not write a suitable event listener which could be used. Another option which is implemented below is that the user actively sets the dropdown value for e.g. the year (before the plot is not shown), this also works. You may find a better solution or ask a follow-up-question.
---
title: "Climate Vulnerability and Readiness"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---

<style>
.justified-text {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 6em;
  margin-right: 6em;
}

/* Media query for mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .justified-text {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding-top: 4em; 
  }
  .sidebar-panel, .main-panel {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .tabset-panel {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .sidebar-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .shiny-output-error {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-panel, .content {
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .titlePanel {
    padding-top: 4em; 
  }
  .shiny-bound-output {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .shiny-frame {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

/* Media query for desktop devices */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .main-panel {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
</style>

# Introduction {.tabset}
<div class="justified-text">

As climate change impacts continue to unfold, countries around the world are grappling with the challenges of adapting. The magnitude of this struggle varies, with some nations more vulnerable due to their geographic locations or socio-economic conditions. Conversely, certain countries are better positioned to adapt—benefiting from more favorable conditions—and can leverage public and private sector investments, government initiatives, and community engagement to drive effective responses. Here, we take a look at how countries rank both in terms of how vulnerable and how ready they are to face climate change challenges.

While every nation must confront the reality of climate change, the disparity in vulnerability and readiness underscores a critical issue of global inequality. Often, the countries most at risk are also the ones least equipped to respond effectively, lacking the necessary resources and infrastructure. We must raise awareness about this pressing inequality, highlighting the urgent need for a more equitable approach to climate resilience and adaptation support. It is imperative that we acknowledge and address the unfair burden placed on the most vulnerable nations.

For more insight into the data used, please see this paper. The source data can be accessed here.

As climate change impacts continue to unfold, countries around the world are grappling with the challenges of adapting. The magnitude of this struggle varies, with some nations more vulnerable due to their geographic locations or socio-economic conditions. Conversely, certain countries are better positioned to adapt—benefiting from more favorable conditions—and can leverage public and private sector investments, government initiatives, and community engagement to drive effective responses. Here, we take a look at how countries rank both in terms of how vulnerable and how ready they are to face climate change challenges.

While every nation must confront the reality of climate change, the disparity in vulnerability and readiness underscores a critical issue of global inequality. Often, the countries most at risk are also the ones least equipped to respond effectively, lacking the necessary resources and infrastructure. We must raise awareness about this pressing inequality, highlighting the urgent need for a more equitable approach to climate resilience and adaptation support. It is imperative that we acknowledge and address the unfair burden placed on the most vulnerable nations.

For more insight into the data used, please see this paper. The source data can be accessed here.

As climate change impacts continue to unfold, countries around the world are grappling with the challenges of adapting. The magnitude of this struggle varies, with some nations more vulnerable due to their geographic locations or socio-economic conditions. Conversely, certain countries are better positioned to adapt—benefiting from more favorable conditions—and can leverage public and private sector investments, government initiatives, and community engagement to drive effective responses. Here, we take a look at how countries rank both in terms of how vulnerable and how ready they are to face climate change challenges.

While every nation must confront the reality of climate change, the disparity in vulnerability and readiness underscores a critical issue of global inequality. Often, the countries most at risk are also the ones least equipped to respond effectively, lacking the necessary resources and infrastructure. We must raise awareness about this pressing inequality, highlighting the urgent need for a more equitable approach to climate resilience and adaptation support. It is imperative that we acknowledge and address the unfair burden placed on the most vulnerable nations.

For more insight into the data used, please see this paper. The source data can be accessed here.

</div>

# Analysis {.tabset}

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

combined_vul_data <- 
  structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
"AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
"BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
), vul_capacity_Rank_2021 = c(0.709035449, 0.511126182, 0.523332101, 
NA, 0.740026186, 0.621133795, 0.446088596, 0.462491218, 0.296565054, 
0.26689445, 0.47917568, NA, 0.453936004, 0.649876424, 0.398904506, 
0.386808093, 0.27763708, 0.547525366, 0.763503499, 0.635633065
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

combined_readi_data <- structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
"AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
"BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
), readi_readiness = c(0.246442145333371, 0.410559121234659, 
0.33334509314068, 0.478714965470705, 0.268117798333208, 0.449260130429268, 
0.376037316185072, 0.50573276439272, 0.690552124980166, 0.68230738466746, 
0.447625682772037, 0.427831425066084, 0.519334145918882, 0.281041117917878, 
0.53612684461446, 0.490112049917615, 0.600207432355383, 0.333388191619152, 
0.337878182675485, 0.483057133272884)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))


# Define UI for the map and table
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
        float: left !important;
        text-align: left !important;
      }
      .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
        margin-left: 0.5em;
        width: 200px;
      }
      .table-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
      .table-container .table-controls {
        margin-right: 2em;
      }
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .table-container {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .table-container .table-controls {
          margin-right: 0;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
        }
        .shiny-input-container {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
          width: 100%;
        }
        .main-panel, .content {
          height: calc(100vh - 56px) !important;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        .main-panel {
          height: 100vh;
        }
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel(div(span("Country Rankings"), style={'padding-top: 15px'})),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Map",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("year", "Select Year", choices = c("", 2021), selected = NULL),
          selectInput("category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_vulnerability"),
          textOutput("category_context")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          htmlOutput("map")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Table",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("table_year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("table_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_capacity")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput("vulnerability_table")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Readiness Map",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("readiness_year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("readiness_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Overall Readiness" = "readi_readiness"), selected = "readi_readiness"),
          textOutput("readiness_category_context")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          htmlOutput("readiness_map")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Readiness Table",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("readiness_table_year", "Select Year", choices = 1995:2021, selected = 2021),
          selectInput("readiness_table_category", "Select Category", 
                      choices = list("Economic" = "readi_economic", 
                                     "Governance" = "readi_governance", "Overall Readiness" = "readi_readiness",
                                     "Social" = "readi_social"), selected = "readi_readiness")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          DTOutput("readiness_table")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic for the map and table
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$category_context <- renderText({
    context <- switch(input$category,
                      "vul_capacity" = "The availability of social resources for sector-specific adaptation. In some cases, these capacities reflect sustainable adaptation solutions. In other cases, they reflect capacities to put newer, more sustainable adaptations into place.", "")
    context
  })
  
  output$map <- renderGvis({
    if (input$year == "") return ()
    year <- input$year
    category <- input$category
    
    # Create the column name for the selected year and category
    rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
    
    # Filter and prepare the data
    map_data <- combined_vul_data %>%
      select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
      mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
    
    
    # Update locationvar column
    map_data <- map_data %>%
      mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name))
    
    # Determine the range of the Rank values
    min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Create the map
    gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                 hovervar = "Tooltip",  
                 options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                width = "100%",
                                height = 500))  
  })

  output$vulnerability_table <- renderDT({
    year <- input$table_year
    category <- input$table_category

    # Prepare data for the table
    table_data <- prepare_table_data(combined_vul_data, year, category)

    # Calculate min and max rank
    min_rank <- min(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)

    # Generate a color scale
    color_scale <- colorRampPalette(c('#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000'))(max_rank - min_rank + 1)

    # Render the interactive table
    datatable(table_data, options = list(
      dom = 'Bt',
      pageLength = -1, 
      autoWidth = TRUE, 
      scrollY = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 0, className = 'dt-right')
      )
    ), 
    rownames = FALSE, 
    filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plainText = TRUE), 
    escape = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle('Rank', 
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(seq(min_rank, max_rank), color_scale),
                  color = 'black')
  })

  output$readiness_category_context <- renderText({
    context <- switch(input$readiness_category,
                      "readi_readiness" = "Overall readiness measures a country's ability to leverage investments and convert them to adaptation actions. It combines economic, governance, and social readiness scores to provide a comprehensive measure.",
                      "")
    context
  })
  
  output$readiness_map <- renderGvis({
    year <- input$readiness_year
    category <- input$readiness_category
    
    # Create the column name for the selected year and category
    rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
    
    # Filter and prepare the data
    map_data <- combined_readi_data %>%
      select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
      mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name)) %>%
      mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
    
    # Determine the range of the Rank values
    min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Create the map
    gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                 hovervar = "Tooltip",  # Use the Tooltip column
                 options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                width = "500px",
                                height = "500px"))  
  })

  output$readiness_table <- renderDT({
    year <- input$readiness_table_year
    category <- input$readiness_table_category

    # Prepare data for the table
    table_data <- prepare_table_data_readiness(combined_readi_data, year, category)

    # Calculate min and max rank
    min_rank <- min(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)
    max_rank <- max(as.numeric(table_data$Rank), na.rm = TRUE)

    # Generate a color scale
    color_scale <- colorRampPalette(c('#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000'))(max_rank - min_rank + 1)

    # Render the interactive table
    datatable(table_data, options = list(
      dom = 'Bt', 
      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      pageLength = -1, 
      autoWidth = TRUE, 
      scrollY = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 0, className = 'dt-right')
      )
    ), 
    rownames = FALSE, 
    filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plainText = TRUE), 
    escape = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle('Rank', 
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(seq(min_rank, max_rank), color_scale),
                  color = 'black')
  })
}

# Prepare data for the table
prepare_table_data <- function(data, year, category) {
  rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
  
  data <- data %>%
    select(ISO3, Name, !!rank_column) %>%
    rename(Rank = !!rank_column) %>%
    mutate(Rank = ifelse(is.na(Rank), "Insufficient data", Rank)) %>%
    select(Rank, Country = Name) %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(Rank))
  
  return(data)
}

# Prepare data for the readiness table
prepare_table_data_readiness <- function(data, year, category) {
  rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
  
  data <- data %>%
    select(ISO3, Name, !!rank_column) %>%
    rename(Rank = !!rank_column) %>%
    mutate(Rank = ifelse(is.na(Rank), "Insufficient data", Rank)) %>%
    select(Rank, Country = Name) %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(Rank))
  
  return(data)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```


This works perfectly, Jan. Thank you! I have more vulnerability categories in reality so I reordered them in selectInput so that the one I want to show first when landing on the page is listed first and then selected = NULL for category, keeping the year selected as 2021. It's a flawless solution. Thank you so much.

Glad to hear, you are welcome. I was hoping you can implement such a solution.

Just one last thing. Any idea why there is so much blue above and below the land masses on mobile screens? On desktop, it appears fine but on my mobile phone screen, the height of the water above and below the countries is huge.

I think that this is connected to the hard-coded height = "500px" which is not suitable when a smaller width is applied, what is the case when you are on mobile. You could experiment with setting other values. Does this yield a good result? Otherwise it would be possible to set up a JS manipulation for cutting it off ...

Ah, you're right. It is that argument - I was experimenting with the wrong one. I can live with the result of 400 px. Thanks Jan!!
